# change the width of UItableviewCell in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

how to change cell width to this image, make my cell as the cell of picture as the cell width less than tableview width 
here is the image
https://lh3.ggpht.com/icMxgsMtJPkx_RfVk-z7p6hdIralZvNq2KEsKb-YaGmcXP5bucASwDXkT4smiYvhSEXW=h310

Comment: Instead of attempting to change the cell's frame, change the size of the cell's `contentView`, or add a background image to the cell. Changing the frame of the cell itself, might result in unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Check the width of cell by 
cell.frame.size.width equal to the height of image view , u can check the height in interface  Builder . Simillarly u can change the height

Comment: Do this in cell for row at indexpath

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.frame.size.width = imagview.frame.size.width;
```

put this code in -cellforrowatindexpath  this code is for programmatically changing the size of cell her we are equating the cell's width to the width of imageview ...
similarlly we can change the height of cell also by

```
cell.frame.size.height = imagview.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve a design as in the image, you might also create an image with a transparent border, add it to the cell's `backgroundView` and set the cell's `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]`.